# fixed url: url end tags should not be changed

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets

Developing a web application and it can be accessed using say...

www.testsite.com/testsite/login.jsp

on successful login, this will be redirected to home.jsp and then the url would look like

www.testsite.com/testsite/home.jsp. Instead, I want to see something like static url like www.testsite.com/testsite/ independent of the redirections of the page.

I mean to say redirections can happen, but the user should not see those redirections. for him, it should only be the website main url. 
In this case , it is www.testsite.com.

would like to hear something apart from putting whole of it in iframes.
Tried Iframes stuff, but dint feel right

Is there anyway out to implement this?

Comment: What do you mean with: _"Independent of the redirections of the page"_

Comment: website has login page...www.testsite.com/testsite/login.html. Now after logging in, the page redirects to home page ..www.testsite.com/testsite/home.html. I want to the hide the end tags ../login.html and /home.html. Url should remain constant through out he navigations..

Comment: Using the same URL to serve completely distinct content/pages looks like a bad practice to me. Even modern single page applications have to deal with [problems related to having just one page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application#Browser_history). Which bring us to: what problem are you trying to solve? Why do you want to avoid redirects?